# Is there any way to find out the current username from the Symfony2 AppKernel.php?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

First off I don't care how this is solved, I would be happy with a solution at all.

I need to create an application that allows the users to dynamically activate/deactivate bundles.

To make it easier, and to save myself from a headache, I won't use
Doctrine, but save a file into the users directory
`dir:/users/{username}/activated_bdls.ini` and loop through the files
from the `AppKernel.php` to activate the bundles accordingly.

Its as easy as pushing the new directories into the bundles array depending on the configuration file:

```
$bundles[] = new Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\DemoBundle();
```

At the moment the file that is looped through has a hard-coded path 
`dir:/users/{hardcoded_username}/activated_bdls.ini`, which needs to be replaced with the current username.

I tried using this, doesn't work, but might give you an idea.

```
$current_username = new \Gabriel\LayoutBundle\Controller\profileController; 
$current_username = $current_username->getCurrentUsernameAction();
```

Comment: the container is not yet booted in the `registerBundles` AppKernel class method.... I'm wrong?

Comment: All standard symfony libraries are already pushed into the array at this point, but the registerBundles() method hasn't returned a value yet.

Comment: @user3531149: Yes, I dind't noticed that you need it into AppKernel and not into Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Appkernel gets loaded again everytime the user reloads the page,
So after the user logs in, set the current user session variable

```
// logincontroller
$_SESSION['username'] = $this->getUser()->getUsername();
```

//since the page gets reloaded on login, you can access it from the AppKernel

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    read_stuff_from = ':dir/'.$username.'/file'
    for(loop_through_logic)
    {
       doStuff()
    }
}
```

I won't set this question as best yet in case you come up with a less dirty solution

Answer (score 0):

> Certainly I can't see why you'd ever want the bundles different on a
>   per-request basis.

maybe to save headaches you can write the username when you are in Controller-scope (some index/landingpage or better at login_check) into a file  e.g /users/currentuser

and in your AppKernel you could read this file, sth. like:

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel {

    private $currentUser;

    public function __construct($environment, $debug) {
        parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
        $this->currentUser = trim(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../users/currentuser'));

    }
```

Comment: two questions, 
1- The appKernel is the first file that gets loaded from the index, if I call a construct funtion from there, doesn't that mean, that no bundles have been registered at this point to begin with?
2- Also how do I deal with multiple users, if I save the current user directly?

Comment: 1: yeah but you set the property $currentUser, in your registerBundles() you can access it, so you can if($currentUser == "foo"){$bundles[] = new FooBundle()}, 2. have headaches ... :/

Comment: I need to get the current user from the Session, at some point I have thousands of users, and if(username == 'somthing') won't be enough :/

Comment: afaik its not possible to access the security-context from appKernel as it is part of a "not yet" registered  bundle itself ..

Comment: sth. that comes to my mind is some kernel event listener

Comment: Please consider posting your solution since any changes to the bundles in AppKernel will require the cache to be completely rebuilt on each request.  I just don't see how it can work in a production environment.